# Intuition behind the notion of reflection positivity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wick-rotation

I came across [Yuji's question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34486/reflection-positivity-in-general). I'm finding it difficult to parse the meaning behind what's [said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_function) on Wikipedia. Could someone give an explanation of the concept involved? I would also appreciate references.