Reflection positivity and $i\epsilon$ in Green's function
There are several ways to tell you why there is $i\epsilon$ in physical Green function, like from direct derivation of $\langle\Omega|\text{T}{\phi(x)\phi(y)}|]\Omega\rangle$, or from path integral formalism by considering insertion of states in far past and far future.
Both methods are related to consideration of causality.
However, Schwartz QFT section 14.4.2 gives another point of view that confuses me.
It says that $i\epsilon$ is required by the condition of reflection positivity.
The derivation is by defining reflection positivity in Euclidean signature and perform Wick rotation to Lorentz signature, which give the correct $i\epsilon$.
To me, defining reflection positivity in Euclidean signature is equivalent to have unitary Lorentz theory, so I think what really gives contribution to $i\epsilon$ would be Wick rotation?

Maybe they are correct, but I personally do not think that we should be giving such a silly little nice trickery such a pompous name. To keep up with manifest Lorentz invariance, integrals should be made of Lorentz invariant parts, so 3D integrals should be upgraded to 3+1D integrals. However, the naïve upgrade would not work, because the integration path hits two singularities, necessitating some way to avoid them. By the time QFT rolled onto the scene, complex analysis, especially residue theorem, is required education, and so one just needed to play around to discover this trick.

@naturallyInconsistent I think the idefication of $i\epsilon$ is important because it tells us the physical Green function is defined on real axis and above the real axis(due to the positive infinitesimal $\epsilon$)

I think you are somewhat talking past me. Whether it is $p\to p\pm i\varepsilon$ or it is $m\to m\pm i\varepsilon$ is a choice of the potential inclusion or exclusion of the 2 roots. One of these choices is the purely retarded Green's function, another is the purely advanced Green's function, we usually pick the Feynman's choice, but we could easily pick the anti-Feynman choice or whatnot. The trick only just tells us which choice of Green's function is being meant when we write down that integral, a reverse definition using residue theorem, if you will.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34486/2451 and links therein.
